# Open accordion using onfocus on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open accordion on onfocus on input field.I have tried but it is not happening .i want to open accordion  depending onwhich input box is focus

```
<input type="text" id="rnv" class="form-control"  placeholder="Ex: Roasted Aparagus and Musherooms" onfocus="accordion('rntip',this)">

<textarea class="form-control"  id="in" rows="6" placeholder="Ex: bunch fresh asparagus, trimmed; 2 sprigs fresh rosemary, minced" onfocus="accordion('intip',this)"></textarea>  
<script type="text/javascript">

function accordion(id,obj){
$(document).ready(function(){

        var accordion = id; 
        var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');
        var accordionToggleIcon = $(this).children('.toggle-icon');

        // toggle accordion link open class
        accordion.toggleClass("open");
        // toggle accordion content
        accordionContent.slideToggle(250);

        // change plus/minus icon
        if (accordion.hasClass("open")) {
            accordionToggleIcon.html("<i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i>");
        } else {
            accordionToggleIcon.html("<i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i>");
        }
});     


}
</script>

 <div class="accordion-container"> <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle1" id="rntip"> <span class="toggle-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>Recipe Name</a>
                  <div class="accordion-content">
                    <ul>
                      <li>Keep it short.</li>
                      <li>Include the name of the dish or its main ingredients.</li>
                      <li>Add a personal touch/get creative.</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you're already using jQuery why not use the `$(element).on('focus', function()...)` method.  Then just use a `data-` attribute to hold which accordian.

Comment: can u help with present code

Comment: Well you might want to make sure `accordion` is referencing the accordion and not just the string you pass.  change `var accordion = id` to `var accordion = $("#"+id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `accordion` is referencing the `accordion` element and not just the string you pass.

Change `var accordion = id;` to `var accordion = $("#"+id);`